# Django template queryset.example_set.all() showing different primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

```
{% for n in medrec %}
            <tr>

                <td>{{ n.patient.pk }}</td>
                <td>{{ n.patient.name }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="ui grid">
                    <form class="ui form" id="mform{{ n.id }}" action="/mbill/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input value="{{ n.pk }}" type="hidden" name="pk">
                        {% for m in n.med_set.all %}
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="eight wide  column">{{ m.medicine }}</div>
                            <div class="eight wide  column">
                                <div class="field"><input name="{{ m.medicine.id }}" type="text"></div>
                                <h5>{{ m.medicine.quantity }} left</h5>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="right aligned">
                    <button  type="submit" class="ui button green" form="mform{{ n.id }}" id="mbill">bill</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

I am trying to access pk of foreign keys of medrec or n. but instead of real pk it show 1,2,3... every time
the n.medicine.id gives 1,2,3... instead of the real 3,4,5 is there a work around for this?

```
class Medicine(models.Model):
    medicalrec = models.ForeignKey(MedicalRec,related_name='med_set')
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(Stock,related_name='stock_set')
    stockpk = models.IntegerField()

class MedicalRec(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    date = models.DateField()
    disease = models.TextField()
    treatment = models.TextField()
    billed = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: show your models

Comment: It's not clear why you think these values are wrong. `m.medicine.id` will show you the PK of the Stock object that is related to your Medicine instance. If that is not what you want, you should explain what it is you are hoping to get.

Comment: you are trying to get the id of medicine while you want is medicalrec. so change it to n.stock_set.all

Comment: i want the id of Stock model. What should i change in code to achive that?

Comment: told you n.stock_set.all instead n.med_set.all

Comment: ok. let me try... i will update soon

Comment: nope.. not working as you can see there is no foreign key link with stock model and medrec